# How to change black background to white in Opencv

Tags: opencv

How to change black background to white

Is there a way to change the black area to white in the image??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbrF1.png)

test image here

Comment: If the background is a solid color, just `flood-fill` it with white

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 

 ...

# image in this case is your image you want to eliminate black
image[np.where((image==[0,0,0]).all(axis=2))] = [255,255,255]
```

Comment: Only a white screen appears as a result of the execution.

Comment: vote for the answer if you find it Helpful